# How to center a SearchBar in React Native Elements

Tags: react-native, uisearchbar, react-native-elements

I am new to React Native and am using React Native Elements to build a UI for an app I am creating. My problem is that I can not seem to get the search bar placed in the middle of the screen. Is there a prop or something that I am missing.

Comment: please share your implementation. for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **styles** for `containerStyle` prop for `SearchBar`

```
<View styles={{ flex:1 }}>
   <SearchBar
      placeholder="Type Here..."
      onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
      value={search}
      containerStyle = {{ alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center' }}
   />
</View>
```